# View will appear did not getting call

Tags: iphone, tabbar, viewdidload, tabbarcontroller, viewwillappear

In my application i am using a tabbar. First time when the app is loading it calls the functions in the `viewDidload`. But when I click on the other tabs and click back the 1st tab again i need to call the functions in `viewWillAppear`. It didnt call when i click back on 1st Tab again. Any Idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your UITabBarController delegate method (didSelectViewController) call `[viewController viewWillAppear:YES];` and then you should be fine.

Comment: You should never, ever manually call methods that fire on events, such as `viewDidLoad` or `viewWillAppear`. If they aren't firing it's because something else is going on. Trying to call them manually will cause endless problems.

Comment: Man you awesome ... this is the exact answer for this ... I did it and work perfectly for me. Great Answer :)

Comment: UIViewController base class has code that runs in viewWillAppear. You _will_ run into unexpected problems if you call this manually.

Comment: I already tried..it's works But animation is stopped unexpectedly

Answer (score -1):

call [super viewDidLoad] or [super viewWillAppear] wherever you want.
But i would suggest you to create generic method(which you are trying to implement in viewDiDLoad or viewWillAppear) and call first time that method in viewDidLoad/viewWillAppear and after that whenever tab bar button is clicked call your method.

Comment: Never do this. See my comment above.

Comment: @Harkonian what's wrong you found in my answer, you did not read my answer fully i suggested him to do in another way as well.

Comment: You should never call [super viewDidLoad] or [super ViewWillAppear] -- ever -- outside of the view controllers viewDidLoad or viewWillAppear methods.

Comment: But i gave the hack solution for that, that i why i add my suggestion to my answer.